# Visual Studio 2008 debugging question

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

I've had an issue with Visual Studio that has been bugging me for some time. Whenever I debug a program that uses the C++ STL and I use Step Into the debugger shows me the code in the files where the data structure I'm using is implemented.

How can I turn this feature off? I want the debugger to always stay in the file that I'm debugging.

SOLVED thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to not enter in other files that the one currently displayed in the debugger, do not step into (F11 shortcut) but use Step Over (F10 shortcut).

Answer (score 1):

you can also selectively disable certain methods you do not want to step into in the registry. Google for 'NoStepInto', [example](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-292148.html).

Answer (score 0):

If managed code is calling this, you can decorate the caller with the [DebuggerStepThroughAttribute class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerstepthroughattribute.aspx)  or one of the other classes in the [System.Diagnostics Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15t15zda.aspx)